# Criar um índice pesquisando parte do texto apenas

Tags: r

Gostaria de criar um índice pesquisando apenas parte do texto.

```
x <- c(4, 1, 6, "ab", 2, 1, "aa")

which(x == "a")
```

No vetor acima, por exemplo, gostaria que o retorno fosse

```
[1] 4 7
```

Ou seja, retornar todas as linhas que contém a letra "a", independente se tiver mais alguma coisa, linha ou letras.

Comment: Benvindo ao StackOverflow em Português!
Experimente utilizar grep("a", x) e grepl("a", x)

Answer (score 4):

Como já indicado nos comentários, `grep` e suas variantes servem para isso:

```
grep("a", x)
#> [1] 4 7
```

A opção `value` mostra os valores:

```
grep("a", x, value = TRUE)
#> [1] "ab" "aa"
```

Use `grepl` para retornar um vetor lógico. Veja a ajuda para expressões regulares (`?regex`) se precisar de padrões mais elaborados.